# Change Color of material ui List Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the color of a material ui list element:

```
<ListItemText primary={mspvar} secondary="buy">
```

Comment: @DBS no, it would change the entire element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it like this.

```
<ListItemText primary="mspvar" style={{ color: 'red' }} secondary="buy"  />
```

Typography is optional.

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

<ListItemText primary={<Typography variant="p" style={{ color: 'red' }}>mspvar</Typography>}
                     secondary="buy"  />
```